# Selenium Webscraper for a jobsite breaks at a specific point in the progress. What to do? Where is the issue?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I built this webscraper to monitor job positions of a football club. I wrote it months ago, and it worked until like one week ago. Now, it has multiple issues.

Either way. I tried to fix it, changed things around (mainly to get away from css selectors that are seemingly changing over time) and now I have a huge problem in the process but I don't know what causes it.

It is supposed to open the website, scroll down to see the job offerings, then find the jobs, open them in a new tab, scrape the data, apply some logic to put them into an excel sheet, close the tab, find the next one until everything is catalogued.

So what happens is, it opens the first link, scrapes it (I think but am not sure if that works yet, although I do get the output in the terminal when I run it, so 95% sure), and then breaks because it can't find the "linkTitle" on line 61.

I have an older version of the code that used to work until maybe one week ago, suddenly it didn't work at all any more, and I decided to change it to xpaths as the css selectors obviously are not consistent.

What is going on with this code, why does it not work?
Why does it break there?

I have made changes to the code.

The original https://codefile.io/f/lM454HVawf stopped working, as mentioned, so I started changing CSS selectors for Xpath selectors, and changed the find() function (as it suddenly didn't work any more)

```
line 61, in <module>
    link = jobitem.find("a", class="linkTitle")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find'
```

But for the breaking of the line 61, I am really not sure why that happens. If I watch the programm work, I can see it seemingly DOES find a link, opens it, scrapes it, and then it breaks before it makes it back to the main tab with the job openings.

Current code looks like this:
https://codefile.io/f/MpPBnw74o3

Comment: Appears to be you are mixing parsing with Selenium webelements with beautifulsoup parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be you are mixing parsing with Selenium webelements with beautifulsoup parsing.

`jobitem.find("a", class="linkTitle")` is beautifulsoup syntax. But the error is saying `jobitem` is a webelement, which is Selenium. So you are trying to apply a beaufulsoup method on a selenium WebElement object.

When I run your code, there are no job listings, likely because this page is dynamic and `class="item-jkL6m item-AunLv"` doesnt exists, so I'm not going to debug any further.

Another reason to not dive into it deeper is there is an API. Far better in that the structure will come in a robust, reliable json format, and you can get the data that way while also being more robust in that it's not reliant on html. The html might change (like in the case of your script crashing), but this json format which is where the site gets the data wont (or if it does, quick fix)

Use this as an example (you'll have to play with the parameters in the site to see how it affects the payload):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://pcw-api.softgarden.de/widget-api/job-list/jobAds/'
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://bvb.career.softgarden.de/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

payload = {
    "userId":"adefc525-5998-4c50-88de-93be42d7d85b",
    "projectId":"ece34058-a9af-457d-a8e2-02d50e895ee5",
    "pageId":"28ae1960-1490-4dd2-831c-a3ceb318aa37",
    "isStandalone":False,
    "locale":"de",
    "isActiveCustomJobPages":True,
    "isUseLayoutsOfSubsidiaries":'False',
    "filterStatus":{
        "careerLevel":False,
        "category":True,
        "partnership":False,
        "location":False,
        "company":False
    },
    "pageNumber":1,
    "numberOfJobsOnPage":9999999,
    "listState":{
        "search":"",
        "location":{},
        "filters":{},
        "filterPredictions":{}
    },
    "jobListTitleNew":"Neu",
    "isGetFilters":True,
    "isForCurrentLocale":False
}

jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()
```

**Output: just showing you the first 5 rows of 31 that it returned**

```
print(df.head().to_string())
   jobPostingId originalJobPostingId                                                                                                               imageSrc                          layoutId                                    title                                                    link        date             workTime       careerLevel partnership  location                                categories                                category                                               linkTitle                                         linkCareerLevel                                            linkCategory                                            linkLocation                                             linkCompany                                                linkDate                                                 linkTag                                                                                        src        id                           encodedTitle  new  coords.lat coords.lng
0      43024814                 None          https://pcw-cdn.softgarden.de/presets/job-category-manager/sam42_education/education-and-social-policy-07.jpg  8971251ad5df45fa9be0ae113a9d532a                   Pädagogische Fachkraft            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/  06.03.2024             Vollzeit   Berufserfahrene        None  Dortmund                    [Bildung und Soziales]                    Bildung und Soziales            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            ./jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/            //karriere.bvb.de/jobs/43024814/P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft/?locale=de&sa=false  43024814            P%C3%A4dagogische-Fachkraft  Neu  51.5135872  7.4652981
1      43020005                 None  https://pcw-cdn.softgarden.de/presets/job-category-manager/sam42_administration/administration-and-secretariat-08.jpg  8971251ad5df45fa9be0ae113a9d532a  Event-Koordinator (m/w/d) Stadiontouren  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  06.03.2024             Vollzeit   Berufserfahrene        None  Dortmund          [Administration und Sekretariat]          Administration und Sekretariat  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  ./jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/  //karriere.bvb.de/jobs/43020005/Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren/?locale=de&sa=false  43020005  Event-Koordinator-m-w-d-Stadiontouren  Neu  51.5135872  7.4652981
2      42784959                 None  https://pcw-cdn.softgarden.de/presets/job-category-manager/sam42_administration/administration-and-secretariat-07.jpg  8971251ad5df45fa9be0ae113a9d532a              Werkstudent (m/w/d) Empfang              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/  01.03.2024  Voll- oder Teilzeit        Student/in        None  Dortmund          [Administration und Sekretariat]          Administration und Sekretariat              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              ./jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/              //karriere.bvb.de/jobs/42784959/Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang/?locale=de&sa=false  42784959              Werkstudent-m-w-d-Empfang       51.5135872  7.4652981
3      42618128                 None                          https://pcw-cdn.softgarden.de/presets/job-category-manager/sam42_manualwork/manualwork-07.jpg  8971251ad5df45fa9be0ae113a9d532a                      Greenkeeper (m/w/d)                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/  27.02.2024             Vollzeit   Berufserfahrene        None  Dortmund  [Handwerk, Dienstleistung und Fertigung]  Handwerk, Dienstleistung und Fertigung                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     ./jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/                     //karriere.bvb.de/jobs/42618128/Greenkeeper-m-w-d-/?locale=de&sa=false  42618128                     Greenkeeper-m-w-d-       51.5135872  7.4652981
4      42545664                 None                            https://pcw-cdn.softgarden.de/presets/job-category-manager/sam42_marketing/marketing-01.jpg  8971251ad5df45fa9be0ae113a9d532a         Junior Manager (m/w/d) eFootball         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/  26.02.2024             Vollzeit  Berufseinsteiger        None  Dortmund             [Marketing und Kommunikation]             Marketing und Kommunikation         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         ./jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/         //karriere.bvb.de/jobs/42545664/Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball/?locale=de&sa=false  42545664         Junior-Manager-m-w-d-eFootball       51.5135872  7.4652981
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the same answer I got from reddit.

If you read the question carefully you'll see that I did mention that one code stops working because it's not dynamic and I tried to change it, but then I hit a wall.

Current code addresses that and has the other issue, that I am after. The original code was more or less just as reference.

The beautifulsoup and selenium mix up might be something to look into.

If you could look at the latest code and help me debug that one, that would be a lot more helpful. For me it's just being stubborn and trying to understand it now.